# Auto-open perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, perspective

I'm developing an eclipse plugin in which I included a custom perspective.
I'd like to get a similar behaviour to the Java perspective. That is that when creating a Java project eclipse will ask you whether you want to open the respective perspective for this...

I found out that I can set a `finalPerspective` as well as `preferredPerspectives` for a wizard but nothing happens if I specify my perspective there.

So what do I have to do in order to get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your New Project wizard should call

```
BasicNewProjectResourceWizard.updatePerspective(configElement);
```

in your `performFinish` when the project has been created.

`configElement` is the `IConfigurationElement` for your new wizard. You get this by making your wizard implement `IExecutableExtension` which adds the method:

```
public void setInitializationData(IConfigurationElement config, String propertyName, Object data)
```

which gives you the configuration element.